# version of Chrome supported by Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I am trying to build a simple AngularJS application using an old Chrome (version 2010).
Then I am facing various problems with routing. Basically Chrome becomes unstable, even crashes often.

I suspect that my old Chrome is not compatible with the specific AngularJS I am using (v1.3.8).

Where can I find such information? I mean the version of Chrome needed by AugularJS of specific version?
I searched AngularJS document, but didn't get a clue.

**Edited:**

Quoted from link https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/misc/faq:

*We run our extensive test suite against the following browsers: Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera 15, IE9 and mobile browsers (Android, Chrome Mobile, iOS Safari). See Internet Explorer Compatibility for more details in supporting legacy IE browsers.*

I think these details above are a little vague as a reference. I understand the recommended practice is upgrading Chrome to the latest. As "Derek 朕會功夫" commented, my environment is restricted to some extent. One of the restrictions is, it is not feasible to upgrade Chrome.

That is why I want to find out the exact Chrome version supported by AngularJS. People may come up with similar concerns with other browsers like Firefox. Right?

### thanks!

Answer To PSL: I am not using bangrang.
BTW, "add a comment" link doesn't work for me , so I have to comment here :(

Comment: *suspect*? Why do you think so? Any error appeared?

Comment: @Raptor - OP mentioned "Chrome becomes unstable, even crashes often".

Comment: Do you have batarang extension installed and enabled, i had experienced it before and it just went off after disabling batarang.

Comment: @raver If the `add a comment` button doesn't work for you, then there must be something installed on your browser that is causing issues.

Comment: Not updating Chrome means you're using a version with loads of security holes and bugs. Why on earth should it not be feasible to update Chrome for 5 years?!?

Comment: @Jürgen'Kashban'Wahlmann: Whilst it may be feasible to update one's own computer, it's not always feasible to explain to one's clients that their website does not work on their customers' browsers because their customers are running old software.  According to a statcounter.com, over the past 30 days around a quarter of Chrome and Firefox users in North America identified as *more than* 2 versions behind the current stable release.  How can one make informed decisions regarding the suitability of a library like AngularJS without a more detailed understanding of its exact browser requirements?

Comment: @eggyal: We're talking 5 years old browser versions, not months old, right? I can understand why the AngularJS developers do not test their framework against browsers more than one or two years old. Every browser that old is a severe security risk to the IT of the Company. Perhaps that should be communicated to the client. Heavens, they should fire the ones responsible for this immediately and get someone serious.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, it's not a company running old browsers. Nevertheless, barely any of the current javascript frameworks were around five years ago, so at one point in time one has to make a decision to cut old ropes. I wouldn't recommend supporting 5 years old browsers to anyone.

Comment: @Jürgen'Kashban'Wahlmann: I completely agree.  I just would like to know *which versions* the framework *has* been tested against and is known to support.

Comment: @eggyal : I understand. Did you try opening an issue about that over at AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you require [Chrome 13](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) from [2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_release_history) in order to support the functions tested in the Angular source found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/431b9c76b05f2bab693e05b60d3c50b51a1459ee/misc/demo/assets/app.js#L267), such as `File` and `Blob`.